# Merge particle system (hair)

Tags: particles, hair

How to merge particle hair guides into one particle system ?
There is an addon called Hair_extension_toolkit on blender market that seems to have the function.
https://s3.amazonaws.com/markets-rails/uploads%2F1602637387000-6.gif